# How to get own quote-item-field to order-item?

Tags: magento, quote

I want to save custom information in `order_item-table`. These information where created in cart. So I do it like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11093017) post.

I have installed the attribute:

```
$installer->addAttribute('quote_item', 'final_delivery_time', $settings);

$installer->addAttribute('order_item', 'final_delivery_time', $settings);
```

declare the fieldset in config.xml

```
<fieldset>
        <sales_convert_quote_item>
            <final_delivery_time>
                <to_order_item>final_delivery_time</to_order_item>
            </final_delivery_time>
        </sales_convert_quote_item>

        <sales_convert_order_item>
            <final_delivery_time>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
                <to_invoice_item>*</to_invoice_item>
                <to_shipment_item>*</to_shipment_item>
                <to_cm_item>*</to_cm_item>
            </final_delivery_time>
        </sales_convert_order_item>
</fieldset>
```

and some code in cart for example

```
$oQuote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach ( $oQuote->getAllItems() as $_item )
    {
        $orderItemId = $_item->getId();
        $_item->setFinalDeliveryTime('some Value');
        $_item->save();
    }
```

so I got a quote and I have my field `final_delivery_time` with this value in the `sales_flat_quote_item` table

After I place the order in `onepage-review`, I should also have this field in the `sales_flat_order_item table`, but there is nothing. In the column stands `null`.
So I need the value of the field saved in the order.

Comment: Please specify the file path and the place in the code where you place your last code bit.

Comment: For testing I do this in an helper and call them in the .../template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml in my design with `echo $deliveryTimeHelper->setDeliveryTimeInOrder();`. This works, because I see the value per phpmyadmin in the table sales_flat_quote_item. I also called it in the review-step in checkout with `public function getDeliveryTimeInOrder()
 {
  $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
  $delTime = '';
  foreach ( $quote->getAllItems() as $_item )
  {
   $delTime.=$_item->getFinalDeliveryTime();
  }
  return $delTime;
 }`

Comment: after Place Order the value is still in the sales_flat_quote_item table , but not in the sales_flat_order_table

Comment: can you trace and check if `getQuote()` returns you the quote object?

Comment: yes, i try this with `Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems();` and `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();` and when I go through the items, I got the correct value (`$_item->getFinalDeliveryTime();`)

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution

it's an observer
I add the following code

config.xml

```
...  
<events>
        <sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
            <observers>
                <quoteitem_set_custom_data>
                    <class>DeliveryTime/observer</class>
                    <method>setCustomDataOnQuoteItem</method>
                </quoteitem_set_custom_data>
            </observers>
        </sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item>
</events>
...
```

Observer.php

```
...
public function setCustomDataOnQuoteItem(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
    $orderItem = $observer->getOrderItem();
    foreach ( $quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item )
    {
        if ($_item->getSku() == $orderItem->getSku())
        {
            $orderItem->setFinalDeliveryTime($_item->getFinalDeliveryTime());
        }
    }
}
...
```

so everything is saved in the order